# NavigationDrawer animation on multiple Activities

Tags: android, layout, navigation, drawer

I wanted to choose the approach using a navigationDrawer in multiple activities using an AbstractActivity which hosts the NavDrawerl layout and initialization and my inherited activities just set there layout as a content of the drawerLayout. Everything works fine, the Drawer is reachable anywhere. A click on one List item should then start a new activity.

I chose to try this because i don't want one single activity which than hosts 10k lines of code implementing all my inter process communication and background service stuff. Everything works fine. except that the Drawer indeed is closed on my new started activity. this isn't nice because normally if you select something from the list it slides back pretty nice. I wanted to find a compromise and just animate the closing in the new activity which wouldn't make much of a difference. but i can not get it to work because all my calls

```
public abstract class AbstractNavDrawerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                    int oldBottom) {

            }
        });
        // mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                    }

                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                    }
                };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        ViewGroup flContent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);
        flContent.addView(getContentView());

        ViewGroup leftDrawer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        MenuFragment mf = new MenuFragment();
        mf.setListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_drawer, mf)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("close")) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("close")) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("close")) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("close")) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract View getContentView();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, OneActivity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent it = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("close", true);
            startActivity(it);
            break;

        case 2:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public class OneActivity extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity {

    @Override
    protected View getContentView() {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ac_one, null);
    }
```

does anybody have a clue how we could get this to work looking "cool". I think it would be a nice solution for complex apps. I don't like the One Activity 1943209483280 Fragment Action Listener approach.